# Swift : Logo on navigation bar along with back button

Tags: ios, swift, uinavigationbar, back-button

I want to have the logo of my app followed by the app name on the navigation bar. Along with this, there should be a back button.

Below is a screenshot :

[image: Screenshot for question]

I've tried the code below.

```
 self.navigationItem.setHidesBackButton(false, animated:true);

 let imgLogo : UIImage = UIImage(named:"Logo")!
 let imgViewLogo : UIImageView = UIImageView(image: imgLogo)
 imgViewLogo.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, 40, 40)

 let leftItem:UIBarButtonItem = UIBarButtonItem(customView: imgViewLogo)
 self.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem = leftItem
 // App Name set on storyboard at design-time
```

This places the logo on top of the back button shown below.

[image: Screenshot 2]

How can this be achieved?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use custom view for `navigationItem.titleView`. Create UIView with your logo and a label for UIViewController title and set
`navigationItem.titleView = YOUR_CUSTOM_VIEW;`

Answer (score 1):

Instead of using `.leftBarButtonItem` use:

```
let imgLogo : UIImage = UIImage(named:"Logo")!
    let imgViewLogo : UIImageView = UIImageView(image: imgLogo)
    imgViewLogo.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, 40, 40)

    let leftItem:UIBarButtonItem = UIBarButtonItem(customView: imgViewLogo)
    self.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItems?.append(leftItem)
```

It will be added along with the system back button
[image]

Comment: Didn't worked. It shows back button and App name only.

Answer (score 0):

You can find tons of example about it.

In this example I've added also a space to centered well your logo if you needed:

```
let leftButton: UIBarButtonItem = UIBarButtonItem(image: UIImage(named: "Logo")!, style: UIBarButtonItemStyle.Plain, target: self, action:#selector(MyViewController.leftButtonPress(_:)))
let negativeSpacer = UIBarButtonItem(barButtonSystemItem: UIBarButtonSystemItem.FixedSpace, target: nil, action: nil)
negativeSpacer.width = -5.0 // Left inset to better center your logo
navigationItem.leftBarButtonItems = [negativeSpacer,leftButton]

func leftButtonPress(sender: AnyObject?) {
    // do whatever you want when you press back button
}
```

Comment: Still the same. I want back button, logo and then App name is sequence

Comment: I don't know if you have seen leftBarButtonItems instead of leftBarButtonItem, it can permit you to add more than one elements ;)

Comment: I've checked both property earlier ;-)